# CSS - Hover trigger on another hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover, element

I wonder whether it is possible to trigger the last hover in this css along with the second one:

```
.social-menu ul li a:hover {
    transform: rotate(0deg) skew(0deg) translate(0, -10px);
}

.social-menu ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
    background-color: #007bb5;
}

.social-menu ul li .fa:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

I noticed that the third hover is triggered on a quite small area resulting in

[image: this]

rather than

[image: this]

HTML:

```
<div class="social-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/akhacklander/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: so do you mean the second one is beat others ?

Comment: @fadiomar well I want the third one to apply when '.social-menu ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover' applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the second element you wish to put into a hover state is a child or sibling of the primary element, you can add a rule to target the hover state of the primary element and apply the same style to the second element as would a direct hover on the secondary element.

**Parent-child**

.parent-element:hover .hovering-child,
.hovering-child:hover { background-color:red; }

**Sibling**

.element:hover ~ .sibling,
.sibling:hover { background-color:red; }

**in your case:**  instead of third one add this

```
.social-menu ul li a:hover .fa {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

if you want just to effect the first item in the list :

```
.social-menu ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover .fa {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you would like to interact `i` while hovering `a`

```css
.social-menu ul li a:hover {
    transform: rotate(0deg) skew(0deg) translate(0, -10px);
}

.social-menu ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
    background-color: #007bb5;
}

.social-menu ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover .fa {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="social-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/akhacklander/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```